# react hook's setState does not appear to be updating the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have tree like component where nodes are expanded and unexpanded to reveal and hide more nodes.

I am have a play with hooks and I am a bit confused how the clickhandler should work:

```
const Tree = ({ tree }) => {
  const [rootNode, setRootNode] = useState(getHierarchy(tree));

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
      rootNode.data.isExpanded = !rootNode.data.isExpanded;

      setRootNode(rootNode);
  }

  return <ExpandableTree tree={tree} onClick={clickHandler} />
}
```

The problem is that the value of `rootNode.data.isExpanded` never changes.

How does `useState` work in this scenario?

Comment: you aren't calling clickHandler anywhere

Comment: I am in the real example, I'm just trying to keep it simple.  I'll update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the original `rootNode` object, you should be passing a new object to `setRootNode()`

Comment: FYI - this is no different to the standard `setState` function, there to objects / arrays should be treated as immutable